# Widget Shapes and Widget Impact Checks

Tags: python, widget, kivy

Im new on Python-Kivy library. So im working hard on kivy's documentation.For now i can create a mini games like characters moves,jumps,background moves etc. In widget controls, im using collide_widget option for check widgets impacts.So i have 2 questions about these:

***1- My image's widgets are ALWAYS RECTANGLE. So when i try to use collide_widget for not rectangle images (like character or ball) Python giving me return 'TRUE'. Because i can't define image's widget's like ellipse or something custom shape.Is there any selection for make these widgets ellipse or somethng else for collide_widget controls.***

***2- Im seeing only 'collide_widget' control for widgets impact controls? Is there any other check ways for widgets impacts.If so , can you give me a documentation for read and learn.***

Thanks for answering already..As you can see im new at Kivy so these widget controls made me fatigue.If there no any option for change this images widgets to ellipse or custom shapes ( like character ) should i use integral for check this image's outside position controls ..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any selection for make these widgets ellipse or somethng else for collide_widget controls.

Implement your own collision detection that does what you want, and optionally override collide_widget with that implementation.

> Im seeing only 'collide_widget' control for widgets impact controls? Is there any other check ways for widgets impacts

Kivy is not a physics engine, its widget layer is primarily there for the purposes of constructing a gui. If you want collision functionality, code it yourself or use a library. For instance, pymunk is an advanced and powerful option.